# Server blocks ports after reboot

Tags: php, postgresql, server, centos, ports

I have a system in **JSP** and **DB PostgreSQL** running on a **CentOS 7 server** however the error happened in a test VM running **Lubuntu**

I made an `API` in `PHP with Laravel` that sends and receives requests from an APP mobile

Until then everything was working correctly, but if I restart this server I lose the connection with the DB, it will return me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

If I try to access the DB through `pgAdmin`, this returns `Connecting to database ... Failed.`

The VM accesses correctly through the `XenCenter console`, however the `SSH connection` that **previously connected correctly** is presented `Network error: Conection refused`

It is as if after restarting blocking all the ports, but until the firewall is disabled

[EDIT]

After some tests I discovered that the problem happens only after enabling **mod_rewrite**

Comment: Slightly lost with what's exactly going on but my first guess is do you have Postgres enabled to start on boot?

Comment: It's standard as it comes in the installation, I did not hit anything

Comment: @GauravJagtap I discovered that the problem is being caused in some way by `mod_rewrite`